# Twig: Print the value of a variable where the variable name is String

Tags: php, twig

I have a variable named e.g. `var1` which has value `value1` as string.
How can I print the value of variable `var1` where `var1` is obtained as string?

Let

```
{{ set container = 'var1' }}
```

The value of the variable `container` is dynamic. Depending on the value of `container`, I need to print its value; in this case, I need to print the 'value1'.

I am looking for something like this

`{{ attribute(this, container) }}` /* <= This will not since `this` is not defined in Twig */

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was wrong.

You can use the `_context` variable which contains all variables passed to the template.

Try `{{ dump(_context) }}`

[Relevant Documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#global-variables)

You can create a function that gets passed this context and the array key to access that value.

This twig function should work fine:

```
public function getAttribute($context, $key)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $context)) {
        return '';
    }

    return $context[$key];
}
```

With the variables being passed `title=foo` and another variable being passed `refTitle=title`, this should output "foo".

```
{{ attribute(_context, refTitle) }}
```